# How to pass information to a fragment when an item on a listfragment is clicked

Tags: android, interface, communicator

I have a fragment list SecondActivityListFragment that contains a list of items. If an item on the list is clicked, I would like to pass the info of this clicked item to another fragment called ItemViewFragment. I have created an interface class called Communicator but I have no clue how to pass the information through.

SecondActivityListFragment

```
public class SecondActivityListFragment extends ListFragment {

Communicator communicator;

private ArrayList<SubNote> subNotes;
private SubNoteAdapter subNoteAdapter;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    communicator = (Communicator) getActivity();
    subNotes = new ArrayList<SubNote>();
    subNotes.add(new SubNote("Product X", "wow", "booo", new     BigDecimal(10212).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR), SubNote.Category.HEALTHCARE));
    subNotes.add(new SubNote("Product Y", "wow", "booo", new BigDecimal(107866.23).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR), SubNote.Category.DENTAL));
    subNotes.add(new SubNote("Product Y", "wow", "booo", new BigDecimal(107866.23).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR), SubNote.Category.DENTAL));
    subNotes.add(new SubNote("Product Y", "wow", "booo", new BigDecimal(107866.23).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR), SubNote.Category.DENTAL));
    subNotes.add(new SubNote("Product Y", "wow", "booo", new BigDecimal(107866.23).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR), SubNote.Category.DENTAL));
    subNotes.add(new SubNote("Product Y", "wow", "booo", new BigDecimal(107866.23).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR), SubNote.Category.DENTAL));
    subNotes.add(new SubNote("Product Y", "wow", "booo", new BigDecimal(107866.23).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR), SubNote.Category.DENTAL));
    subNotes.add(new SubNote("Product Y", "wow", "booo", new BigDecimal(107866.23).setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR), SubNote.Category.DENTAL));

    subNoteAdapter = new SubNoteAdapter(getActivity(), subNotes);
    setListAdapter(subNoteAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);



    launchNoteDetailActivity(position);

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof Communicator) {
        communicator = (Communicator) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement Communicator");
    }
}

private void launchNoteDetailActivity(int position){


    ItemViewFragment itemViewFragment = new ItemViewFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, itemViewFragment, itemViewFragment.getTag()).commit();

    //communicator.respond(position);

    // Grab the note information associated with whatever note item we clicked on
    //SubNote subNote = (SubNote) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

}
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, Communicator {

//public static final String SUB_NOTE_NAME_EXTRA = "com.example.khalid.myapplication2.SubNote Title";
//public static final String SUB_NOTE_BRIEFDESCRIPTION_EXTRA = "com.example.khalid.myapplication2.SubNote BriefDescription";
//public static final String SUB_NOTE_FULLDESCRIPTION_EXTRA = "com.example.khalid.myapplication2.SubNote FullDescription";
//public static final String SUB_NOTE_PRICE_EXTRA = "com.example.khalid.myapplication2.SubNote Price";
//public static final String SUB_NOTE_CATEGORY_EXTRA = "com.example.khalid.myapplication2.SubNote Category";

// ViewPager viewPager;
// CustomSwipeAdapter imgadapter;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    MainActivityListFragment mainActivityListFragment = new MainActivityListFragment();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, mainActivityListFragment, mainActivityListFragment.getTag()).commit();



   // viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager1);
   // imgadapter = new CustomSwipeAdapter(this);
   // viewPager.setAdapter(imgadapter);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    return true;
}


  /*  @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }*/

  @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
  @Override
  public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        MainActivityListFragment mainActivityListFragment = new MainActivityListFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, mainActivityListFragment, mainActivityListFragment.getTag()).commit();
        setTitle("ThimarAljazirah");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_notification) {

        NotificationsFragment notificationsFragment = new NotificationsFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, notificationsFragment, notificationsFragment.getTag()).commit();
        setTitle("Notifications");

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_messages) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_categories) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_deals) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
        SettingFragment settingFragment = new SettingFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, settingFragment, settingFragment.getTag()).commit();
        setTitle("Settings");
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_help_contact) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_profile) {
        MyProfile myProfile = new MyProfile();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, myProfile, myProfile.getTag()).commit();
        setTitle("My Profile");

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_signout) {
        SingOutFragment singOutFragment = SingOutFragment.newInstance("1", "2");
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,singOutFragment, singOutFragment.getTag()).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_about_us) {
        AboutUsFragment aboutUsFragment = new AboutUsFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main,aboutUsFragment, aboutUsFragment.getTag()).commit();
        setTitle("About Thimar Aljazirah");
    }


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}


@Override
public void respond(int position) {

    ItemViewFragment itemViewFragment = new ItemViewFragment();



}
}
```

ItemViewFragment

```
public class ItemViewFragment extends Fragment {


public ItemViewFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_view, container, false);
}

}
```

Communicator

```
public interface Communicator {
public void respond (int position);
}
```

Comment: You are using interface as a callback to the activity. So read this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both fragments are in the same Activity, this activity can implement a listener(interface) that listens for a click from fragment A and transfers data to the fragment B.

```
 public interface Communicator{
     void onResponse(YourData data);
 }

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Communicator {

     @Override
     public void onResponse(Your data) {
         // add data to other fragment
     }
 }
```

In order to pass the data to the activity, you have to get the listener from inside of the fragment.

```
 YourFragment extends Fragment {
    private Communicator communicator;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        Object host = getHost();
        if (host instanceof Communicator) {
            communicator= (Communicator) host;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        communicator= null;
    }
}
```

Then when onClick happens for the list view. You have to do.

```
onClick {
    communicator.onResponse(//your data here);
}
```

In the other fragment B you have to create a newInstance(//Your data) method like this.

```
public static YourFragment newInstance(String string) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(STRING_KEY, string);
    YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment ();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

and then onCreate you can retrieve the data given to the fragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String string = getArguments().getString(STRING_KEY);

}
```

you shouldn't use the default constructor to instantiate the fragment because of the way Android recreates fragments and activities. That's why we create newInstance method.

Comment: As shown in my code, fragment B (or ItemViewFragment) gets created when the list item is clicked. So fragment B is considered to be a child of fragment A

Comment: In the first step, how can I add data to the other fragment? if you look at "SecondActivityListFragment" class. The data are being added to the list by using the ".add" method and  "subNote" is an object of my data structure class.

Answer (score 0):

**Communicating with Other Fragments of activity**

1>.Define an Interface

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
    public void onArticleSelected(int position);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}

...
```

}

2>.implement the interface into Activity.

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
...

public void onArticleSelected(int position) {
    // The user selected the headline of an article from the HeadlinesFragment
    // Do something here to display that article
}
```

}

3>.The host activity can deliver messages to a fragment by capturing the Fragment instance with findFragmentById(), then directly call the fragment's public methods